# How to make regex match across multiple lines in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a javascript file with millions of lines. The problem is that IE doesn't support `,` (comma) followed by `}` (curly close bracket).

In Notepad++ I'm able to find all the commas which are being followed by a curly close bracket, by using this regular expression: `\,.*\}`.

But when the comma and the curly close bracket are not in the same line, the regex doesn't match it:

```
somestring,

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is check `. matches newline` in Notepad++ Search/Replace Search Mode:

[image]

This will make the dot `.` in your regex match newline, so `.*` will match any number of newlines.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in notepad version. Updated to notepad++ v6.1.8 and this regular expression worked `\,[\r\n\s]*\}`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I tested this out using the following and got it to work:

REPLACE - **,\r\n\r\n\s+}**

WITH - ‹blank›

***NOTE:** In my Replace tab I have "Wrap around" checked with Search Mode set to "Regular Expression" and I am using Notepad++ v6.4.3.*