# notepad++ regex length in bytes

Tags: notepad++, regex, ascii

I am struggling with coming up with a regexp in notepad++ that finds and replaces x number of bytes with nothing. Carriage return (0D) counts, line feed counts (0A).

This is the regex I am trying: (0C is my begin, I am removing 318 bytes after 0C along with the 0C)

```
\x0C(.{318})
```

This regex doesn't find anything, it says no match found. I can find `\x0C`, and I can find `.` but I can't find `.{318}` also `.` skips over 0x0A and 0x0D

-wrap around is checked.

-regular expression is checked.

Here is part of the file in hex with ascii:

```
0C 30 31 32 27 34 35 36 0D 0A 30 61 32 0D 33 34 0A [snip] 0C 32 0A 0D 35 [etc..]
<ff>0  1  2  '  4  5  6<cr><lf>0  a  2<cr> 3  4<lf>[snip]<ff> 2<lf><cr>5 [etc..]
```

Comment: So what's your problem and what doesn't work about it? What does your input and output actually look like?

Comment: one thing you could try is converting the file to hex, and run the regex on the hex, so the file will look a little bit like the one you show, but then you don't do \x0C you do 0C literally.   Your way, looking for the hex eg \x0C  may work too if it's ascii so every char is a byte anyway.   But include the file here like upload the file to http://ge.tt and include a link in your question. And re your concern about whether or not dot matches new line, you can toggle it https://superuser.com/questions/481276/how-to-make-regex-match-across-multiple-lines-in-notepad

Comment: The round brackets are superfluous so you can remove them. Also, try changing 318 to a much smaller number like 3, see if that matches anything. Then troubleshoot, find at what point it doesn't match.

Comment: @barlop I didn't have that option for `.` so I updated and now everything works great... I don't really know what to do with my question now though.

Comment: @UpTide doesn't matter  you could just leave it.  It's good that you found the issue and cause of the problem you had.

Comment: @UpTide: Are you *sure* you want to count *bytes* and not character codepoints? Depending on your encoding, one character can consist of multiple bytes. Also "." in regex does not match linebreaks, so it's to be expected that it skips over 0A and 0D.

Comment: @Wouter yes, it is bytes. The file is encoded in us-ascii. You can view information about it in this [PDF](http://sliderule.mraiow.com/w/images/7/73/ASCII.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned the encoding is us-ascii, we can assume each character is one byte. In regex, the '.' matches any character, except newlines, and you want each individual part of a CR/LF newline to be matched separately, since they are two bytes.

I'm also going to make the assumption that you are processing actual text data, and not a binary file that can contain bytes outside of the us-ascii character mapping.

If all of the above is true, you can use the following regex:

```
\x0C[^\xFF]{318}
```

The reason the '.' didn't work in your attempt, is because the '.' does not match newlines. You also can't use `\x0C[.\r\n]{318}`, because the '.' wildcard is not available within a character class (square bracket group). The Hex value FF does not map to any valid codepoint inside the us-ascii character set, and hence when you look for "any character that is not the FF character", you will be taking *bytes* into consideration.

Keep in mind that this method counts windows/mac Newlines as two characters/bytes (per your request).

Hope this is what you were looking for...

## EDIT - Regex explained

#### Full expression

```
\x0C[^\xFF]{318}
```

Let's break this down.

#### \x0C

This matches a Single Unicode Grapheme, you can find more information on this [over here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). In summary, You can consider \x the Unicode version of the dot, except that **it can also match line-breaks** (this is important, more on this later).

But, since you also used this, I'm guessing you're already partly familiar with this.

#### [^\xFF]

Everything between [] is called a [Character Set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (not to be confused with the same concept in Character encoding). You can read more about it on Regexp Tutorial, but in summary, it serves as an "OR" statement. [ab] simply means, "a or b". When ^ is used inside a character set, it serves as a negation. So [^a] means "not a". In our use-case, we look for any character that is not the HEX value FF.

#### {318}

And we look for this kind of character, 318 times. The {} syntax always applies to the Regex element just in front of it, so in this case the [^\xFF] Character set.

#### Why \xFF?

In Hexadecimal notation, the us-ascii character set goes [from 00 up to 7E](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html). Any value higher can not be mapped to a us-ascii codepoint. This means that any file encoded (correctly) in us-ascii, can only contain HEX values between 00 and 7E. As a result, it can't contain FF.

So, we can cleverly make use of this to search for any character including newline characters, since \x.. also matches newlines like \x0A and \x0C. When we search for any character that is **not** FF, we end up finding **every** character.

Keep in mind that this solution is dependant on the fact that your file is encoded in us-ascii, and not UTF-8.

Comment: while your regex works great, I would love a walkthrough on what each part of it does. For some reason I have not been able to wrap my mind around regex statements.

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: Oh and, it's normal that you can't wrap your mind around regex statements. http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 mastery of regex takes a decade :)

Comment: Your explanation is superb. If I understood this correctly, then this finds x0C, selects it, then selects the next 318 bytes (even if it is a x0C). This selects 319 bytes, including the x0C. Thanks! I feel like I need to make more accounts to uptick you more.

Comment: Haha, thanks :) And yes, you understood this correctly.